# Override :hover on elements under pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, compass-sass

In our menu, I have a parent menu item and its children turn orange on :hover. I am also using JS to add a toggle to a collapse/expand menu, but since the span element is positioned on top of the parent list item, hovering on the toggle triggers the color change.  I am trying to figure out a way (either with Compass or jQuery) to override the hover style on the list if the toggle is hovered on.

We're using Drupal, so the HTML is quite convoluted, but here's a pared down version:

```
<li class="menu__item is-expanded last-expanded">
  <span class="menu__link nolink">About</span>
  <span class="menu__link nolink expand"> </span> <!--put here by jQuery for the collapse and expand icon -->
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="mission.html">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(".not-front .menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span").after("<span class='menu__link nolink expand'>&nbsp;</span>");
      $(".front .menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span").after("<span class='menu__link nolink expand collapse'>&nbsp;</span>");
      $("#block-menu-block-1 ul li li").css({ display: "block" });
      $(".not-front #block-menu-block-1 ul li li").css({ display: "none" });
      $('#block-menu-block-1 .menu__link.nolink').click(function(){
        $('#block-menu-block-1 ul li li').toggle('fast');
        $( ".menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span.menu__link.nolink.expand" ).toggleClass( "collapse" );
      });
 });
```

And here's the Sass:

```
.menu__item:hover a,
.menu__item:hover span {
  color: $orange;
}
```

Edit: Sorry! I wanted to post a Sassmeister earlier, but their site was down.  Had a link to the dev site, but removed once answered.

Edit: I thought something like this would work, but it's not:

```
jQuery(".menu__item span.expand").mouseover(function(e) {
        jQuery("menu__item:hover a, .menu__item:hover span").toggleClass( "stay-gray" );

});
```

along with this is the sass:

```
.menu__item:hover a,
.menu__item:hover span {
  color: $orange;
  border-color: $orange;
  &.stay-gray {
    color: $darkGray;
    border-color: $darkGray;
  }
}
```

Comment: And the Sass you've got in your sample above isn't changing the `a` and `span` child tag colors to `$orange` on the hovered `.menu__item`?

Comment: That part is working, I just want to be able to override it or avert it when the toggle button is hovered on.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your menu, or create a jsfiddle please? This will make it easier for us to debug your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try stop propagating the event on the `span.expand` elements:

```
$("span.expand").mouseover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**EDIT**: `stopPropagating` didn't work. So, retaking the idea proposed by the OP, we figured out this solution:

Add two new CSS rules:

```
.stay-gray a.menu__link {
  border-bottom-color: #474E51 !important;
}
.stay-gray, .stay-gray a.menu__link {
  color: #474E51 !important;
}
```

And then add this lines at the end of the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ...`:

```
toggleStayGray=function(e){ jQuery(e.target).siblings().toggleClass('stay-gray') };
jQuery('.menu span.expand').mouseover(toggleStayGray).mouseout(toggleStayGray);
```

This way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".not-front .menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span").after("<span class='menu__link nolink expand'>&nbsp;</span>");
  jQuery(".front .menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span").after("<span class='menu__link nolink expand collapse'>&nbsp;</span>");
  jQuery("#block-menu-block-1 ul li li").css({ display: "block" });
  jQuery(".not-front #block-menu-block-1 ul li li").css({ display: "none" });
  jQuery('#block-menu-block-1 .menu__item.is-expanded').click(function(){
      jQuery('#block-menu-block-1 ul li li').toggle('fast');
      jQuery( ".menu__item.is-expanded.last.expanded span.menu__link.nolink.expand" ).toggleClass( "collapse" );
  });
  toggleStayGray=function(e){ jQuery(e.target).siblings().toggleClass('stay-gray') };
  jQuery('.menu span.expand').mouseover(toggleStayGray).mouseout(toggleStayGray);
});
```

This way, when you hover over the `span.expand` element, the `stay-gray` class is toggled on at its siblings, and the new styles are applied on them and its `a.menu__link` descendants. When the mouse is out, the `stay-gray` class is toggled off.

Comment: Thanks! But the one that I don't want orange (while the cursor is on the toggle) is a first generation span.

Comment: Maybe this another way?

Comment: Oh, I haven't used asterisks before.  That is cool.  But it's not that the style isn't applying, it's that it IS applying and I want it NOT to when the mouse is hovering over the span.expand.

Comment: Sorry for the delay :S So you don't want that the `span.expand` be of color orange when the mouse hover it, right? All the descendants, both `a` and `span` must turn orange?

Comment: Great, idea! But it's not that span.expand shouldn't be orange, it's that span.expand is on top of a menu__item span (absolutely positioned), so I don't want the menu__item to be orange when the span.expand is hovered on.  Are you able to see the dev site linked above?

Comment: Also, CSS3 is fine, since it won't cause problems in older browsers...Just won't be as pretty.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it! Sorry, can't access to the site, is asking me for user and password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48089/discussion-between-guillermo-gutierrez-and-beatrice)